# Ajax calendar extender cuts off at bottom

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I used Ajax calendar extender with my custom css classes. These are applied well but problem is that when any calendar which is at bottom of page opens, it get cut at bottom due to restricted boundary of form. How can I overlap on the form boundary and can get full view of Calendar. [image]

In above image blue line at bottom is the form border. Also below are the classes that I used to styling the calendar

```
.calendarContainer
table th
{
    padding: 0!important;
    margin: 0!important;      
    border: 0!important; 
}
  .calendarContainer
table td
{
    padding: 0!important;
    margin: 0!important;      
    border: 0!important; 
}

.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_container   {
    background-color: #DEF1F4;   
    border: solid 1px #A1DCF2;  
     z-index : 10000 ;  
    }

.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_header  
{
       background-color: #ffffff;
       margin-bottom: 4px;

}

.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_title,
.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_next,
.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_prev    {
color: #004080;
padding-top: 3px;
}

.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_body    {
background-color: #ffffff;
```

border: solid 1px #A1DCF2;
    z-index : 10000 ;
    }

```
.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_dayname {
text-align:center;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-top: 2px;
color: #004080;
}

.calendarContainer .ajax__calendar_day {
color: #004080;
text-align:center;
}
```

What could be the appropriate css?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
/* css for Ajax calandar control. */

.Calendar td
{
            text-align: left; 
            padding: 0px; 
            height: 19px; 
            font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
            font-size:12px; 
            color:#333;
}


.Calendar .ajax__calendar_container
{
            background-color: white;
            border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_header
{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_title, .Calendar .ajax__calendar_next, .Calendar .ajax__calendar_prev
{
            color: black;
            padding-top: 3px;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_body
{
            background-color: white;
            border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_dayname
{
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            margin-top: 2px;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_day
{
            text-align: center;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_day, .Calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_month, .Calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_year, .Calendar .ajax__calendar_active
{
            color: #004080;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: silver;              
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_today
{
            font-weight: bold;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_other
{
            color: #bbbbbb;
}
.Calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_today, .Calendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_title
{
            color: Blue;
}

/* End */
```

aspx:

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="cetbDate" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
     TargetControlID="tbFromDate" PopupPosition="TopLeft" CssClass="Calendar">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: you can change the color & style as your requirement.

Comment: Is't showing the page scroll on the page when selecting the calendar at bottom of the page??

Comment: try the above edited aspx page code. there defined the popup position to show the calendar above the textbox. PopupPosition="TopLeft"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30529/discussion-between-eraj-and-watraplion)

Comment: chat page access denied here. try this PopupPosition="TopLeft" property of ajax calendar control.

Comment: :But i need that calendar to be open at bottom

Comment: If it opens at bottom u wil get the scroll on the page n wil show the full calendar.Its happening here. there is it not showing the scroll??

Comment: if u r using the calendar in content page then remove the height of the content placeholder at its master page.